# AWS - Unable to download cloudwatch logs from s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

We have some WAF rules setup on an application load balancer and being logged in cloudwatch. I created an S3 bucket to export these cloudwatch logs to. I am able to read-write to the s3 bucket, view the files, etc- however the download button is grayed out. Unable to download anything from the S3 bucket.

This is the policy on the bucket, what am I missing? This policy was initially created because cloudwatch was unable to export to the s3 bucket. Now that that's working, my user (the user who created the s3 bucket) is unable to download the files contained within.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudWatchLogsPutObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "logs.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3-bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3-bucket-name"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit - I tried the policy listed in the answer below, but still unable to download folders from an s3 bucket in the GUI. I now have the below policy in place. This IAM user is able to download files at the object level, but when trying to download folders of files, or folders containing folders of files, the download button is gray.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Show your IAM policy attached to the user account you are logged into the AWS console with.

Answer (score 1):

You can add new statement in bucket policy which will allow user to download files from S3 bucket.
Update bucket policy is given below:-

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowCloudWatchLogsPutObject",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "logs.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::aws-waf-logs-prod-op",
            "arn:aws:s3:::aws-waf-logs-prod-op/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowUserGetObject",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::aws-waf-logs-prod-op/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, however I am still unable to download from the bucket when signed in with an IAM user. Does that matter at all?

Comment: are you facing this issue with only IAM user? Are you able to download files with root or other users?
Also verify IAM user have permission to download objects from S3 bucket.

Comment: That bucket policy just gives AWS logs access to the bucket. The IAM policy attached to the user account being used in the AWS web console (the question is about using the AWS web console) would be the thing granting or denying access here.

Comment: The root users can download from the bucket but we need to allow a specific IAM user to be able to download from the bucket

Comment: Please check IAM user permission once. That IAM user should have download permission.

Comment: The problem is that this is not our environment it's a clients. Our IAM user does not have permissions to view the list of user or modify user permissions "no identity based policy allows the iam::ListUsers action". Client has confirmed 10x that our IAM user has download permission on the bucket. The IAM user is able to download single files at the object level, but we're trying to download entire folders of objects, and the button is grayed out when selecting a single folder containing objects, or a folder containing folders of objects.